# Current flows from the source towards the sink

Tags: current, resistors, raspberry-pi

I happened upon the following schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwyrZ8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's supposed to reduce the max.voltage between the GPIO input pin and the current source to 3.3V, since 5V * (10K/(10K+5K)) = 3.3V. The thing is - 3.3V is the voltage over the 10K resistor and 1.7V is the voltage over the 5K one. As long as the current flows from the source to the sink, the voltage between the source and the GPIO pin should be 1.7V - what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to ask here. The voltage difference between the 5V rail and GPIO pin is 1.7 because 5 - 1.7 = 3.3V

When GPIO voltage is measured it is measured from that pin to ground, which is 3.3V,.

Comment: You're right, I was incorrectly measuring the voltage between the current source and the GPIO input pin (sink) rather that between the GPIO pin and the sink.

Comment: @Witiko, we're confused because there's no current source in your schematic.

Comment: @ThePhoton: There is a 5V rail above the switch.

Comment: @Witiko, the way you drew it, it looks like a voltage source, not a current source. If it's a current source, you need to say how much current it drives.

Comment: @ThePhoton Not my drawing, as mentioned in the OP. The source can provide up to 50 mA.

Comment: @Witiko, if the drawing doesn't fit your situation, you should make a new drawing. There's a built-in schematic editor in the post editor.

Comment: @ThePhoton Done.

Comment: @Witiko, it still looks like a voltage source, not a current source. So I'm still confused that you draw a voltage source, and then ask a question about a current source.

Comment: @ThePhoton The question's about voltage and voltage solely. The fact that the source provides both voltage and current is insignificant.